# problem with cookies in php

Tags: php, cookies

sorry i changed my question.

```
if( isset($_COOKIE["user"] ) )
    {
        /...
    }
    else
    {


        setcookie("user","",time()+ 3600);

    }
    if( isset($_COOKIE["user"] ) )
    {
        echo "the cookie is set correct";//line 10
    }
```

in this code  line 10 must execute but it doesn't execute why?

Comment: 20 seconds' lifetime is a bit little, isn't it?

Comment: You only set the "user" cookie in your check.php.  Do you do check for the "admin" key afterwards before trying to print it? Your current code example is not clear about that.

Comment: I believe you cannot look if the cookie is set until the page is refreshed..

Answer (score 2):

you do realise that you are saying that the cookie will expire in 20 seconds.... the [PHP Manual on Cookies](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) might help you a little better.
Edit: Now that you have updated your post, it seems that the main issue is that you have never declared $_COOKIE["admin"]

Answer (score 2):

You write a cookie named **user**, but access in the other script a cookie named **admin**.

PHP's message is correct, since `$_COOKIE` does not contain a value for **admin**.

To learn, what's inside of `$_COOKIE` in the second script, perform this

```
print_r( $_COOKIE );
```

instead of echo().